# AWS Load Balancers - All the EC2 instances were failed the health check and stated Out Of Service. Why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks

I was trying to host my API (.NET Core Web API) on Elastic Kubernetes Service in AWS. I followed around some tutorials and get it on EKS now. Everytime I run `kubectl get pods` I can see my service there.

Then in order to exposed the service to API Gateway, I was told that need to create a Load Balancer. So I create a Load Balancer using the `kubectl expose` command and success. Now I can see my Load Balancer is hosted on EC2 with a specific DNS address and able to see it via `kubectl get svc` command.

Here is the problem, according to tutorials, when I access to the specific DNS name with port, example: *****.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com:8000, I should be able to access.

But no, all I get is empty response error from browser. When I go over EC2 pages to check my Load Balancer, I found that all the instances under the ELB is Out Of Service.

The Status of the ELB is: 0 of 6 instances in service

When I switched over to Instances tab, all the 6 instances are showing Out Of Service.

Is this why I could not access to the DNS address? And how can I make the instances In Service?

FYI: What I want to do eventually is using API Gateway to connect to the API on EKS.

Thank you very much if anyone knows how to solve this.

Comment: If you can see the health checks it should give you an error reason. Once you know this it should be easier to identify

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I know its health checks issue because when I hover over the Out Of Service text it gives me: `Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively.`

Comment: The target groups will give a reason for the failure i.e. timeout or incorrect HTTP status

Comment: @ChrisWilliams When I go over Target Groups there is nothing there. Should I create one or?

Comment: What type of ELB are you using?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams A classic one

Comment: Have you checked the http port are your services using? And where your ELB are trying to connect?